# Bootstrap javascript link is not working in Umbraco framework (asp.net)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, umbraco

**below are the script links what I used for my project. please go through it and give me the correct answer. Thanks in advance **

```
<script strong textsrc="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2.3/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/umbraco-starterkit-app.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/home.js")"></script>
```

Comment: Where you included `Bootstrap` ?

Comment: I included my script links in `Master.cshtml` page

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just include the script as it's listed on the Bootstrap site:

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`